# Use Javascript in Rails to add input fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This, I'm assuming, is a very easy task for someone who knows JS.

I just want to have a clean UI for a form field where users can dynamically add as much information as they'd like.

An example:

Let's say I have a group (model). The group form is just a group name and members. The form allows you to add as many members as needed. On the form, there should be either 0 or 1 field shown. When the user clicks a button "`ADD MEMBER`," a row of fields should appear: `:member_name`, `:member_name`, `:member_description`, `:member_role`.

Upon saving, each member is populated into the database as a member of the group.

Comment: This is not a good question for SO. There are a million ways to add fields to a form dynamically with javascript. Try something out or search around for a solution & ask when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, where the association between your two models `Group` and `Member` should be:

```
Group has many Members
Member belongs to Group
```

Checkout this episode by Ryan Bates:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1